# Laravel | Problema con cifrado diferente bcrypt

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, aplicación-web

En el registro de usuarios guardo la clave con bcrypt, y en la autenticacion hago un return de la contraseña y me da un valor de hash diferente de como esta la clave en la base de datos, miren:

clave db: $2y$10$5HZ4raSDAB8WHJgG07yXU.1.9t2M/V3rtk...
clave login: $2y$10$.YCEUONOZpy6BVZqP/tI6u...

En mi sentencia me da falso:

```
    public function store(LoginRequest $request) {

    $correo = $request['correo'];

    $clave = bcrypt($request['clave']);

    return $clave;

    if (Auth::attempt(['correo' => $correo, 'clave' => $clave])) {

       return 'Login correcto'; 

    }else{

        return 'falso';
    }
}
```

¿Que hago mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función bcrypt es solo para generar la clave, no para compararla.

Lo más fácil es que uses 'password' en vez de 'clave' como nombre del campo que la contiene.

Si deseas cambiar el nombre del campo deberás extender un poco el core de Laravel, o utilizar el siguiente código para la comparación:

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Puedes ver más información en la documentación de Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/master/hashing

---

Edición para agregar detalles explicando la respuesta:

Cuando llamas al método `attempt` de Laravel, estás utilizando este código localizado en `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard`:

```
public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false, $login = true)
{
    $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember, $login);

    $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

    if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)) {
        if ($login) {
            $this->login($user, $remember);
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

En el código vemos que un evento es activado y posteriormente llamamos el método `retrieveByCredentials()` del proveedor y una verificación por medio de  `hasValidCredentials()`, también como puedes ver, solo estás pasando el primer argumento, `$credentials`.

Ahora vamos a analizar el código de `retrieveByCredentials()`, localizado en `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider`:

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    if (empty($credentials)) {
        return;
    }

    $query = $this->createModel()->newQuery();

    foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
        if (! Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
            $query->where($key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $query->first();
}
```

Lo que el método hace es encontrar el primer resultado del modelo de usuarios que corresponda a las credenciales que le estamos entregando, el va a iterar por el array que le pasamos PERO si el campo que le pasamos se llama 'password', NO lo va a comparar, la idea es que el método busque un usuario que tenga un email o nombre de usuario X simplemente.

**Creería que en este punto falla tu aplicación, le estás diciendo que compare dos campos: correo y clave, y al comparar clave no funciona por los motivos descritos en la primera parte de la respuesta, antes de la edición.**

Volviendo a nuestro attempt, a continuación llamamos el método `hasValidCredentials()`:

```
protected function hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)
{
    return ! is_null($user) && $this->provider->validateCredentials($user, $credentials);
}
```

Si el resultado del query realizado en el método anterior no es nulo **(lo cual es probable que sí lo sea en este caso)**  y si el resultado del método `validateCredentials()` que veremos a continuación también es verdadero, entonces el usuario iniciará sesión:

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
{
    $plain = $credentials['password'];

    return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
}
```

Lo que hace validateCredentials es simplemente tomar el campo 'password' (el cuál no está presente en tu caso) de las credenciales que le pasamos y compararla con la clave almacenada, este método `check()` lo encuentras en Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher:

```
public function check($value, $hashedValue, array $options = [])
{
    if (strlen($hashedValue) === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return password_verify($value, $hashedValue);
}
```

Nada raro en este método, la documentación de [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php) está en el sitio web de php.

---

**Resumen:**

Es más fácil usar el campo `password` como clave, de lo contrario es posible que debas extender clases o hacer overrides de algunos métodos de Laravel para que funcione tu autenticación o en su defecto hacer tu propia implementación de la autenticación para no pasar por estos métodos.

El resultado podría ser algo así:

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request) {

    $correo = $request['correo'];
    $clave = $request['clave'];

    if (Auth::attempt(['correo' => $correo, 'password' => $clave])) {
        return 'Login correcto'; 
    } else {
        return 'falso';
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo que busco es que el usuario pueda ingresar correctamente, pero no lo logro, yo cifre la contraseña en bcrypt, que necesito para hacer un login correcto?, en mi db la configure como correo y clave...

Comment: Tal y como te digo, lo más fácil es que utilices el campo password en vez de clave, aunque si definitivamente quieres usar esos campos (correo y clave) hay que hacer un trabajo un poco más extenso.

Comment: Entonces tengo que cambiar todo por password y email, el error seguiria igual ya que cumple la misma funcion que clave y correo

Comment: No, Laravel no funciona así, él asume en varias ocasiones que el campo de la clave se llama 'password', si revisas el código fuente lo puedes ver. Claramente debes quitar bcrypt, pues solo sirve para generar la clave, no para poderla comparar.

Comment: Listo @gburu98, ya agregué detalles suficientes que explican porque no usar el nombre del campo 'clave', recuerda que bcrypt es solo para codificar la clave y no para compararla.

Answer (score 0):

Solo quita la función bcrypt para tu variable $clave
dale una leída a su documentacion oficial

[Manually Authenticating Users](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#authenticating-users)

Comment: Hola miguel, le quite la funcion bcrypt, quedo asi:
 if (Auth::attempt(['correo' => $request['correo'], 'clave' =>      $request['clave']])) {
           
           return 'Login correcto'; 

        }else{

            return 'falso';
        }
Sigue sin funcionar, me da falso

Comment: A ver intenta con esto `Auth::attempt(['correo' => $request->correo, 'clave' => $request->clave]);`

Comment: que versión de Laravel estas usando???

Comment: `public function store(Request $request) {

    $correo = $request->correo;

    $clave = $request->clave;

    return $clave;

    if (Auth::attempt(['correo' => $correo, 'clave' => $clave])) {

       return 'Login correcto'; 

    }else{

        return 'falso';
    }
}
`

Comment: Estoy usando la 5.2, desencripte la clave de la db y le puse hola vuelvo pruebo me devuelve hola, despues intento hacer el login y me responde "Undefined index: password", y en la 2da linea de errores me toma el hola como contraseña a la perfeccion pero responde con error...

Comment: a tal vez tu problema radique en tus Modelos en este caso tu modelo **User** al igual que debes de revisar tu tabla de migracion de **User** para ver que campos son los que tienes porque por default en la autenticacion viene como **email** y **password**

Comment: Acabo de revisar el modelo User, y en table y filiable tengo correo y clave, y en las migraciones de la tabla usuarios, tengo correo y clave. La verdad que no se de donde provenga el error :(

Comment: bueno yo tengo esta funcion para validar el usuario tal vez te pueda servir <br/>`function aut(Request $request){
  $validacion = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
   'password' => 'required|min:8',
  ]);
  if ($validacion->fails()) {
               //validacion de campos incorrecta
  } else {
   $valid = Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password],true);
   if ($valid){
    $user = Auth::user();
    return redirect("/");
   }else{
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: ya revisaste tu formulario??

Comment: ah ya se donde podría estar tu error, estas usando la extension **LoginRequest** cámbialo así como en el ejemplo que te envie **Request** ya que en login request tendras que mover arlgunos parametros y ahi en **LoginRequest** es donde pide **email** y **password**

Comment: probe tu codigo, y me dice LoginController does exist, que no existe mi controlador, el formularion funciona bien

Comment: Miguel me dice que Validator no existe, como lo importo a validator?

Comment: `use Validator;`

Comment: Veo que estás llegando a la respuesta que te propuse @gburu98

Comment: Me responde error luego de logearme, se queda en la condicion 
if  ($validacion->fails()) { 
        echo "error";
}

quedo en el mismo error

Comment: @Shaz, tu respuesta no la comprendi. Me la podrias detallar un poco mas es mi primera aplicacion en Laravel...